# Is there a way to bind *ngIf with material theme form to display an image using Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
          RegisterComponent.html:93 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
         at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RegisterComponent.html:93)
         at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36055)
         at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35067)
         at callViewAction (core.js:35433)
         at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:35390)
         at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35068)
         at callViewAction (core.js:35433)
         at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:35361)
         at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35074)
         at callViewAction (core.js:35433)`
```

I am using an SQL database which I was able to display/retrieve all data from, but I find it difficult to retrieve an image to display for each user. Instead, I get the error

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="PhotoName" >
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PhotoName</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" data-label="PhotoName" >
                    <!-- <img class="imgUrl" [src]="ImageUrl"/> -->
                          <div mat-cell 
                      *ngIf="repoService.qns[repoService.qnProgress].PhotoName!=null">
                                            <img class="imgUrl" 

   [src]="repoService.url+'/UploadFile/'+repoService.qns[repoService.qnProgress].PhotoName" 
     style="width: 50px; height:50px;">
                                            </div>
                                        </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your DB response? I think there is an issue in

```
   *ngIf="repoService.qns[repoService.qnProgress].PhotoName
```

as template is unable to find "PhotoName" of repoService.qns[repoService.qnProgress]. Make sure to properly handle errors.

Another suggestion, you can also use "async" pipe to deal with Observables.